# How Can i export the UV lay out, in the same size as my 3d model

Tags: uv, export, import

[image]i just to ask if how can i export the UV layout in the same size as my 3d model, I'm using feet, i want to export my UV layout in feet, i want to export it to CorelDRAW, but whenever i import it to corel the size changed, it goes to inches, i want the same size for printing, because I'm working in an inflatable manufacturing, hope someone could help me, i need this for me to be a regular worker here in our company...

Comment: This is not possible as far as I know, The object exists in 3D space with Blender scene units, while unwrapping is done as a 2D projection, in image space with dimensions as Pixels. There is no possible correlation of size, since unwrapping introduces distortions and different parts can have different scales for each independent island or even faces.

Comment: then, what should i do? is there no any way?

Comment: Can you post images of your model and UV map? If you unwrapped all islands with consistent scale between them, then maybe you can add a "dummy reference geometry" to your mesh, like a large bounding box, or a "ruler face", with known dimensions, and use that as reference for manually scaling your unwrap in CorelDraw

Comment: I need the uv lay out for pattern in sewing, for inflables, wait ill post an image, tnx for the help by the way

Comment: how to add image? im a newbie here ^^

Comment: and how can i unwrapped with consistent scale, even if my objects is in a different size?

Comment: Edit your question and use the image button in the toolbar.

Comment: Partially related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1633/texture-scaling-to-real-world-measurements. The way which should work is by resetting / applying object's scale, enabling Edge Length display and looking up how they match with unwrap. Also check if this depends on import settings from Corel (no idea here).

Comment: how can i enable edge length display?